# Polls application — django tutorial not working

Tags: python, django

I am working through the [Polls tutorial for Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/). I have made it as far as the start of part six.

For some reason all of my class based generic views are working **EXCEPT** the class based index view. When trying to load localhost:8000/ I get the following error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/

Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^polls/
^admin/

The current URL, , didn't match any of these.
```

Here is my mysite/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
   url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

And here is my polls/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = 'polls'

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
   url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
   url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
   url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

And here is the polls/views.py. I am just pasting the IndexView portion. The rest of the class based views are currently working:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import generic
from django.utils import timezone

from .models import Choice, Question

# Create your views here.
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        # Return last five published questions (not inc. future)
        return Question.objects.filter(
        pub_date__lte=timezone.now()
        ).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

Am I missing something? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your index url pattern is in `polls/urls.py`, which you included under `r'^polls/'` so you should access it at:

```
http://localhost:8000/polls/
```

Getting a 404 for `http://localhost:8000/` is expected behaviour, because your main `urls.py` only includes urls at `admin/` and `polls/`. You would have to add a url pattern with regex `r'^$'` to `main/urls.py` to stop the 404.

Comment: Thank you! As an extra bonus your answer taught me how to think about 'index' as it relates to mysite vs. inside the polls app. Much appreciated.